# Moving and Altering First/Last Elements of Array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array containing the following words:

```
@animals = (
    "cat",
    "dog",
    "mouse",
    "elephant",
    "giraffe"
);
```

How would I move element `0` to the end of the array? So now it will become:

```
@animals = (
    "dog",
    "mouse",
    "elephant",
    "giraffe",
    "cat"
);
```

Is there a simple way using `shift`, `unshift`, `pop`, or `push`?

Comment: `push(@animals, shift(@animals))`

Comment: A blog post on using arrays as linked lists. http://blogs.perl.org/users/shawnhcorey/2012/05/a-look-at-arrays.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) removes the first element.
- [`unshift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unshift.html) adds an element to the front.
- [`pop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html) removes the last element.
- [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) adds an element to the end.
- [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) can add and remove any number of elements from anywhere in the list.

`shift`/`unshift` work at the front, `pop/push` work at the end.

In your case, you want `push(@animals, shift(@animals))`. Remove the first element and put it on the end.